# adding a prefix to a file name while downloading from URL via a CSV sheet with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a prefix from one column to a filename. This code downloads a picture from a given URL in a CSV. That file name should have the prefix + filename.
The CSV has two columns, the first with the URLs and the second with a uniqueID named "idnumber"
Its been a while since i coded and maybe mixing SQL with Python...

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request

def url_to_jpg(i, url,file_path ):

    
    filename = 'idname-image-{}.jpg'.format(i)
    full_path = '{}{}'.format(file_path, filename)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)

    print('{} saved.'.format(filename))
    return None


FILENAME = 'Image_Download.csv'
FILE_PATH = 'images/'

urls = pd.read_csv(FILENAME)
idnumber = urls.idnumber

for i, URL in enumerate(urls.values):
    url_to_jpg(i, URL[0],FILE_PATH)
```

Comment: I don't get what you fail to do ? please clarify

Comment: you probably need the full path? you might also want to check that `images` dir is present before attempting to write to that location.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
import time

def url_to_jpg(i, name,url,file_path ):

   time.sleep(5)
   filename = name
   full_path = '{}{}'.format(file_path, filename)
   urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)

   print('{} saved.'.format(filename))
   return None


FILENAME = 'Image_Download.csv'
FILE_PATH = 'images/'

df = pd.read_csv(FILENAME)
name = df.name


for i, URL, in enumerate(df.values):
   url_to_jpg(i, name[i] ,URL[0],FILE_PATH)
```